# How to produce a synthetic dataset demonstrating heteroskedasticity?

Tags: heteroscedasticity, structural-equation-modeling

Consider a hypothetical world in which only three variables exist: X, Y and Z. X causes Y, but Z also causes X and Y (refer below). Assume that this model is complete, and no others factors exist in this world.

[image]

Consider an individual who observes measurements of X and Y only. On plotting the results, they find that there is heteroskedasticity present. This is due to the (unobserved) confounder Z.

I want to create some basic equations that could simulate this problem, but am getting pretty stuck. I tried:

$f_z: z = u_z$, where $u_z$ is drawn from a Gaussian distribution with mean 0 and variance 1.

$f_x$: $x = z + 0.1 z u_x$, where $u_x$ is drawn from a Gaussian distribution with mean 0 and variance 1.

$f_y$: $y = 2x + 0.5 z^2 u_y$, where $u_y$ is drawn from a Gaussian distribution with mean 0 and variance 1.

While this works in generating heteroskedasticity, I don't like it as the $u_x,u_y,u_z$ surely assume that there is some uncertainty not accounted for within the model (i.e. some cause-effects that we're not observing).

Is it possible to generate a fictitious example like the one I'm describing? I'm happy to add more nodes if that's all that's missing -- but I just want to ensure that the fictitious model I'm generating from is fully described.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see how it is problematic to assume there are unmodeled causes that are captured by the residuals of X and Y, unless you want to model Z as accounting for 100% of their variances.  But perhaps a location-scale model for (X and) Y would provide what you are looking for?  Then you could model Z as the only entity responsible for heteroskedasticity, via its effect on the (log-)*SD* of Y's residuals.